# Bootstrap scss compiling error for 1 width columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

Trying to use `Bootstraps official SCSS` but after compiling `col-xs-1, col-sm-1, col-md-1, col-lg-1` are all missing from common grid styling:

**example:**

```
**.col-xs-, .col-sm-, .col-md-, .col-lg-,** .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Where can I find the source of this column list?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I find the source of this column list?

You can find this code [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_grid-framework.scss#L7). This mixin in `assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_grid-framework.scss` looks like that shown below:

```
// [converter] This is defined recursively in LESS, but Sass supports real loops
@mixin make-grid-columns($i: 1, $list: ".col-xs-#{$i}, .col-sm-#{$i}, .col-md-#{$i}, .col-lg-#{$i}") {
@for $i from (1 + 1) through $grid-columns {
$list: "#{$list}, .col-xs-#{$i}, .col-sm-#{$i}, .col-md-#{$i}, .col-lg-#{$i}";
}
#{$list} {
position: relative;
// Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
min-height: 1px;
// Inner gutter via padding
padding-left: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
padding-right: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
}
}
```

The above mixin will be called [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_grid.scss#L48)

Even when you call the mixin with other parameters than default, i do not think it can produce the output described in your question. So probably some post processor will mess up your compiled code.